# 1px border not showing in Chrome mobile

Tags: css

I am using the included CSS, with a sprite image to add in-box icons and inset box-shadows to each of my single line form elements (I removed the url for the image, because it is dynamically defined in the head (CDN issues)).

The form looks great in Chrome, FF, and IE11 on PC, but on Android, the 1px border disappears!

Here's the CSS in question:

```
.textbox {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#8e8d8d;
    font-family:"Droid Sans";
    padding:11px 15px 10px 50px;
    background-color:#fdfdfd;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
    margin:13px 0 -3px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;
    box-shadow:inset 2px 2px 4px #f1f1f1;
}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], select, .remember input[type="checkbox"]+label, .remember input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label { 
    background:url() no-repeat;
    background-size: 39px 297px;
}
input.user     { background-position:0  -31px; }
input.password { background-position:0  -69px; }
input.code     { background-position:0 -107px; }
input.confirm  { background-position:0 -145px; }
input.email    { background-position:0 -183px; }
input.company  { background-position:0 -221px; }
input.phone    { background-position:0 -259px; }
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

For clarity, here is the responsive code used to set the background url:

```
input.textbox, select.textbox, .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]+label, .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    background-image:url('images/page-modal-sprites-1x.png');
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-resolution: 120dpi){ 
    /* Retina images */
    input.textbox, select.textbox, .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]+label, .checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label { 
        background-image:url('images/page-modal-sprites-2x.png');
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

user httpgio has narrowed the issue to the inset box-shadow, removing that causes borders to appear properly.  It also only occurs on mobile chrome.  Dolphin 10 has no such problem.

I'm now looking for a way to keep my box-shadow without losing my border on Android Chrome mobile.

Comment: Disappears? Or is just too hard to see on a small screen? Is it there when you zoom in on Android? What about other OS?

Comment: @Paulie_D Here is a gallery highlighting the issue: http://imgur.com/a/asILJ The border is totally gone, if it is set as 1px.  I don't have any other mobile operating systems on hand.  The only other thing I can imagine effecting this is the conditional code I use to choose between a 1x pixel density background and a 2x pixel density bg, but there is no alteration to the border in there, just a responsive change to background-url... I'll add it to the post, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first step to finding your solution is by telling us what Mobile Browser you are using. Is this on multiple mobile browsers or just a specific one?

```
.textbox {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#8e8d8d;
    font-family:"Droid Sans";
    padding:11px 15px 10px 50px;
    background-color:#fdfdfd;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
    margin:13px 0 -3px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;
}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], select, .remember input[type="checkbox"]+label, .remember input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label { 
    background:url() no-repeat;
    background-size: 39px 297px;
    border:1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
input.user     { background-position:0  -31px; }
input.password { background-position:0  -69px; }
input.code     { background-position:0 -107px; }
input.confirm  { background-position:0 -145px; }
input.email    { background-position:0 -183px; }
input.company  { background-position:0 -221px; }
input.phone    { background-position:0 -259px; }
```

The problem had to to with the box-shadow. The inset box shadow was actually overlapping the border, and not letting it display. Since we can't set a z-index on a property of a CSS element, the next solution is to wrap it with a div and apply the border and border-radius to the wrapper div. However, since he wants a completely minimalistic approach, it was best to leave out the box-shadow.

Comment: The browser I was using is Chrome Mobile for KitKat.  I have tried it in Dolphin 10, and the borders render fine.

Comment: Just saw your gallery... Can you temporarily disable any box shadows, and see if that fixes your problem? If it does it may be a matter of z-index..

Comment: You are correct that disabling the inset shadow causes borders to appear.  But I'd hate to have to remove the shadow because of one browser's bug... is there a way to change the z-index of a box-shadow?

Comment: well, now we know what it is ;-) Can you post me a fiddle with HTML and CSS and I'll fix it for you

Comment: @httpio: don't think i can jsfiddle it... jsfiddle doesn't render properly on mobile, so the problem can't be shown or tested

Comment: Ok, if you haven't fixed it yet, post the *rendered* HTML so I can see how it is nested. Should be no more than 3 lines of CSS to fix

Comment: Why don't you remove the border from the .textarea class..
Wrap each input in a class named .input-wrap or something similar... and then apply the border to that? should work. I thought you had JS overlaying your inputs but I see that's not the case. Do the wrapper fix and you will be set.

Comment: One more thing, you may want to put the border radius properties in the wrapper div as well. I love the way your form looks by the way!

Comment: I might look more into wrapping for the border at some point, but one of the things I'm really going for is totally minimal layout with as semantic markup as I can swing... for now, the effect of the shadow is so minimal that I think I'm going to simply leave it out, and embrace the flat-design feel.  Thanks for the help (and the compliment).. If you edit your answer to summarize this comment thread, I'll mark it accepted.